# Further compact string.join so it replaces apostrophes?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, string

Consider the below code (which dynamically creates a **dynamic** SQL string)

Is there a way to further compact string.join, so it does replace("'","''") on all array members automagically ? (without writing a custom version)

C#:

```
[STAThread()]
public void Main()
{
    string[] astrAllGroups = {
        "Group A",
        "Group B",
        "D'Amato",
        null
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < astrAllGroups.Length; ++i) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(astrAllGroups[i])) {
            astrAllGroups[i] = astrAllGroups[i].Replace("'", "''");
        }
    }

    string strDynSQL = "'" + string.Join("', '", astrAllGroups) + "'";
    strDynSQL = strDynSQL.Replace("'", "''");
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(strDynSQL);
    Console.WriteLine(strDynSQL);


    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine(" --- Press any key to continue --- ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

VB.NET

```
<STAThread()> _
Sub Main()
    Dim astrAllGroups As String() = {"Group A", "Group B", "D'Amato", Nothing}

    For i As Integer = 0 To astrAllGroups.Length - 1 Step 1
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(astrAllGroups(i)) Then
            astrAllGroups(i) = astrAllGroups(i).Replace("'", "''")
        End If
    Next

    Dim strDynSQL As String = "'" + String.Join("', '", astrAllGroups) + "'"
    strDynSQL = strDynSQL.Replace("'", "''")
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(strDynSQL)
    Console.WriteLine(strDynSQL)


    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)
    Console.WriteLine(" --- Press any key to continue --- ")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: If you intend to use that resulting string in a Sql query then you may not need to replace the apostrophes if you use a parameterized query.  Your post didn't indicate if you intend to use it in a sql query, even though the variable seems to suggest that.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: It's an array of parameters merged into a varchar(max) for a dynamic SQL procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
string strDynSQL = "'" + string.Join("', '", 
                       astrAllGroups.Select(s => s.Replace("'", "''"))
                   ) + "'";
```

If you're not using .Net 4, you'll need to add `.ToArray()`

Comment: actually it's s => s == null ? null: s.Replace("'", "''"), or else you get a NULL reference exception. Using  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace won't do the trick. But it looks far more professional now.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using .NET 3 or newer, you could use LINQ:

```
var strDynSql = 
    "'"
    + String.Join("', '", 
                  astrAllGroups.Select(s => s.Replace("'","''")).ToArray())
    + "'";
```